# #regex for validate URL validation

Tags: regex, karate

I do have the following URL

```
https://domain.xyz/version/path/node
```

the node can change but the format must be the same

```
#regex '[0-9a-z]{9}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}'
```

I have read the documentation and looked up examples but I couldn't get it working.

How do I do this in karate?

Comment: That pattern will not match the url, there are no hyphens for example. Which part or what do you want to match?

Comment: That is what I have:


* def SELF_Regex_Path = '#regex /' + baseUrl+ path1 +path2 + '/' +  '[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-0a-z]{4}-[0-0a-z]{4}-[0-0a-z]{4}-[0-0a-z]{12}'

Comment: This pattern `[0-9a-z]{9}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}` has exact quantifiers, meaning the amount of characters to match should be present. Looking at the code, I guess it will match a string like this `https://domain.xyz/version/path/12345abcd-a1b2-1b2a-aaaa-1111111111bb` See https://regex101.com/r/NGPI0E/1

Comment: yes I need the exact quantifiers. The issue I do have is when doing `* match response.content[0].links[0].href == SELF_Regex_Path` 

I am getting this error response:
`getListOfSubscriptions.feature:126 - path: $.content[0].links[0].href, actual: 'https://domain.xyz/version/path/12345abcd-a1b2-1b2a-aaaa-1111111111bb', expected: '#regex /https://domain.xyz/version/path/[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}', reason: regex match failed `

This looks like not be working

Comment: Try this `([0-9a-z]{9}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12})` regex as your first set of value after node si having 9 digits instead of 8 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
* def myUrl = 'https://domain.xyz/version/path/blah-blah'
* def pos = myUrl.lastIndexOf('/')
* def node = myUrl.substring(pos + 1)
* match node == '#regex [0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}'
```